# Excel help - Duplicate in Index and Match function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

TOP IMAGE IS TABLE

BOTTOM IMAGE IS EXTRACT TABLE

The solution pulls the data from the table to the yellow table.

[image]

Chris

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you show us what the expected result should be? I'm not sure I understand why you would not just sort the table on the occupancy rate

Comment: Look into [`SORT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c) maybe?

Comment: Please do not add a large “SOLVED” to the title of the post. If you have an answer, post an answer. If you do not want to post an answer, just delete your question and move on.

Comment: Hi, I put solved but unfortunately it isn't as it has errors. 
So consequently hadn't posted the answer as it is not working. Was seeing if I could get to work to post but unfortunately not. 

Thank you for the feedback and have a great evening

Comment: Please edit your post to show the problems you state. If necessary use a smaller, illustrative dataset rather than your "live" version (doctored for names). You are really leaving it for others to guess that the root cause of your problem lies in column F. If it is, a helper column with unique values may be your solution. (Hint: concatenate value in F to its no. of appearances so far in column F using the mix of absolute/relative cell references exhibited elsewhere in your question).

Comment: Hi, Thank you for taking the to help and give feedback. 
I looked at the helper column but the issue is that sometimes the formulas are exactly the same. I also looked at RAND but have used this before the results were mixed. 

what I really need is a formula that index and matches via rows so that it moves to the next row if the same. I have tried smaller but unfortunately it doesn't illustrate the same errors on a smaller scale.  

Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Winning formula

=INDEX($D$6:$D$215,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($D$6:$D$215)-ROW($D$6)+1)/($V$6:$V$215=AU6),COUNTIF($AU$6:AU6,AU6)))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @cybertinic.nomad on the comments, you can use the `SORT` function (if you have Excel 365) to achieve the desired result. Remove the formulae entered on columns L and M. Enter the following formula on L6:

```
=SORT($E$6:$F$16,2,-1)
```

This sorts the columns E and F based on the values of column F in descending order. Note that the instructors with 83%'s occupancy are correctly listed.

[image: Result using SORT function]

Comment: Thank you: Sorry, A great formula but I'm not sure that sort can work with the data that I am working with. The sheet I am using has many columns but it was suggested to condense to a small range of data (see comments). I had no luck with my previously details post so made it a really small data set. Thank you very much for helping though

Comment: @Chris Based on your previous edit's screenshot, it seems that you can use the FILTER function to filter the data, then use the SORT function.

Comment: Thank you , I will take a look at the filter fucntion. Watching Youtube videos to learn.